# Why some esperanto-speakers call others "samideano"?

Tags: culture, word-meaning

I have seen a lot of old Esperanto speakers in Facebook use the word *samideano* when adressing to other Esperanto speakers. Why are they using this word, and how an Esperanto-speaker is a *member of a same idea*?

Answer (score 11):

It's a reference to "la interna ideo", which Zamenhof described like this: "*La interna ideo* of Esperanto, which is in no way obligatory for any individual Esperantist, but which [...] is and always should be key during Esperanto Congresses, is this: with a neutral linguistic foundation, that barriers between peoples be removed and that people become accustomed to seeing others simply as people and as brothers." (L. L. Zamenhof, 1912, quickly translated here by me).